# Why is the L group of an even unitary group what it is?

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms, l-functions

It is fairly easy to see from the formalism of the L group that the L group of a quasisplit unitary group will be a nontrivial semidirect product of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ (for the appropriate value of $n$), and a group of order two. When $n$ is odd this determines the isomorphism class uniquely. When $n$ is even, it does not. Indeed, an outer automorphism is of the form $g \mapsto A{}^tg^{-1}A^{-1}$ for some $A \in GL_n(\mathbb C).$ It is of order two if and only if $A$ is either symmetric or skew-symmetric. It seems to me that in the literature the $L$ group of a quasisplit unitary group is consistently defined using a skew-symmetric $A.$ Can anyone explain why this is correct?

Comment: It's correct because if you read the actual definition of the L-group it doesn't say "make any old semidirect product", it says "here is the explicit recipe; use this to make your semidirect product". That is strictly speaking the answer to your question. Perhaps some more helpful comments are that you need to figure out the automorphism of the dual gp which gives the correct endomorphism of the dual torus plus pinning corresponding to the endo of the torus coming from the unitary group, and when you do this you'll find that it's conjugation by the antidiagonal matrix (1,-1,1,-1,..) (forall n)

Comment: (PS you should tag your question nt.number-theory; they like a top-level tag on each question here)

Comment: Thanks. I guess I never mastered how to compute the endomorphism of the pinning, since I've worked mostly with split groups. Can you recommend a specific reference?

Comment: I'm afraid I just worked it all out myself one day! Google says this: http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~buzzard/maths/research/notes/unitary_groups_basic_definitions.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three separate issues here: exactly which unitary or special unitary groups you're thinking about (in effect: exactly which non-degenerate hermitian spaces), how to define $L$-groups in general, and how that definition works out in the quasi-split case.

In general, if $G$ is a pinned split connected reductive group over a field $k$ and it has based root datum $(R, \Delta)$ arising from the pinning then via the notion of pinned automorphism we have
$${\rm{Aut}}(G_{k_s}) = G^{\rm{ad}}(k_s) \ltimes {\rm{Aut}}(R, \Delta)$$
compatible with the action of ${\rm{Gal}}(k_s/k)$.
In this way, the pointed set ${\rm{H}}^1(k, {\rm{Aut}}(R,\Delta))$ of conjugacy classes of actions of ${\rm{Gal}}(k_s/k)$ on $(R, \Delta)$ is in natural bijection with the set of $k$-isomorphism classes of quasi-split $k$-forms of $G$, and every $k$-form of $G$ has a unique quasi-split inner form.

For example, if $G = {\rm{SL}}_n$ for $n>1$ then it is simply connected with diagram A$_{n-1}$, so the split form is the only quasi-split form when $n=2$ (as A$_1$ has no nontrivial automorphisms) whereas otherwise the diagram automorphism group has order 2 and so the set of non-split quasi-split $k$-forms of ${\rm{SL}}_n$ is classified up to isomorphism by the set of quadratic Galois extensions $k'/k$ up to isomorphism.  The link is that the group attached to $k'/k$ becomes split over $k'$. But what is it explicitly?  That is where you preferred (special) unitary groups come in.

So now assume $n\ge 3$ and consider the hermitian space $({k'}^n, h_n)$ for a quadratic etale $k$-algebra $k'$ (i.e., a quadratic Galois field extension, or $k \times k$) with unique non-trivial automorphism denoted $z \mapsto \overline{z}$ and the non-degenerate hermitian form $h_n$ defined by 
$$h_{2m}(\vec{x}, \vec{y}) = \sum_{j=1}^{m}(x_j \overline{y}_{m+j}+x_{m+j}\overline{y}_j)$$
for $n = 2m$ and
$$h_{2m+1} = x_0 \overline{y}_0 + h_{2m}((x_1,\dots,x_{2m}),(y_1,\dots,y_{2m}))$$
for $n=2m+1$. There are very many other kinds of rank-$n$ non-degenerate hermitian spaces over $k$ in general.

If $k' = k \times k$ then ${\rm{SU}}(k'/k, h_n)$ turns out to be ${\rm{SL}}_n$ by another name; see Exercise 3 at http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/252Page/homework/hmwk7.pdf
(where ${\rm{SU}}(h)$ for hermitian spaces $(V',h)$ over quadratic etale algebras $k'/k$ are described inside the Weil restriction ${\rm{R}}_{k'/k}({\rm{SL}}(V'))$).   I claim that for $k'/k$ a quadratic Galois field extension, the $k$-group ${\rm{SU}}(k'/k, h_n)$ is the unique non-split quasi-split form of ${\rm{SL}}_n$ that splits over $k'$.

If you look at Example 7.1.10 (and Example 7.1.5) in the article "Reductive Groups Schemes" from the 2011 Luminy summer school on SGA3 (and set the base $S$ there to be ${\rm{Spec}}(k)$) you'll see a description for any $n>2$ of the Galois-twisting encoding exactly the unique non-split quasi-split $k$-form $G$ of ${\rm{SL}}_n$ that is split by $k'/k$, using the pinning associated to the upper-triangular Borel subgroup $B$ and the order-2 automorphism of ${\rm{SL}}_n$ given by $g \mapsto w({}^tg^{-1})w^{-1}$ where $w$ is the anti-diagonal matrix with alternating $1$'s and $-1$'s beginning with $1$ in the upper-right (and the role of transpose is to ensure that $B_{k'}$ is stable under the Galois descent, so the associated $k$-form really is quasi-split).  From that explicit description of $G$ one describes $G(A)$ inside ${\rm{SL}}_n(k' \otimes_k A)$ for any $k$-algebra $A$ as fixed-points of a specific involution, and you can work out that this coincides *exactly* with the description of ${\rm{SU}}(k'/k, h_n) \subset {\rm{R}}_{k'/k}({\rm{SL}}_n)$ (on $A$-points, for any $A$).

So we have learned two things, for all $n > 2$ on equal footing:  the groups ${\rm{SU}}(k'/k, h_n)$ for varying quadratic Galois $k'/k$ really are characterized in terms of the quasi-split property over $k$ and the split property over $k'/k$ as claimed, and we see exactly how they are made from ${\rm{SL}}_n$ via an explicit involutive automorphism over $k'$. We likewise conclude that ${\rm{U}}(k'/k, h_n)$ admits the same Galois-twisting description in terms of ${\rm{GL}}_n$ and $k'/k$ for each $n > 2$. This Galois-twisting description with an explicit involution is what is going to answer your actual question concerning the $L$-group for ${\rm{U}}(k'/k, h_n)$.  But first we have to recall what exact is the definition of the $L$-group.

Strictly speaking, the uniform definition of the $L$-group treating all connected reductive groups $G$ over a local or global field $k$ on an equal footing involves a semi-direct product against the *entire* Weil group $W_k$ of $k$ for a specific action of $W_k$ on the connected reductive $\mathbf{C}$-group $^{L}G^0$ with the dual based root datum, so it has infinitely many connected components. But in practice one passes to the quotient by the finite-index open kernel of the $W_k$-action to collapse it down to a semi-direct product against a finite Galois group ${\rm{Gal}}(k'/k)$.  It is the latter viewpoint you're thinking of, but really that is not the actual definition of the $L$-group (though in practice it works just as well). However you slice it, the real issue is: what is the $W_k$-action on ${}^LG^0(\mathbf{C})$?  Or in our case of interest with $G = {\rm{U}}(k'/k, h_n)$ with $n \ge 3$ and $k'/k$ a quadratic Galois field extension, where it collapses down to an action of ${\rm{Gal}}(k'/k)$ on ${\rm{GL}}_n(\mathbf{C})$ (really the "dual"), what is the associated involution of ${\rm{GL}}_n(\mathbf{C})$?  I claim that it is *exactly* the same recipe which we saw in the very description of $G$ as a quasi-split form of ${\rm{GL}}_n$ obtained by $k'/k$-twisting against the involution $g \mapsto w({}^tg^{-1})w^{-1}$ of ${\rm{GL}}_n$ over $k'$.

In general, the classification of connected reductive groups over fields involves Tits' notion of the $\ast$-action of the absolute Galois group on the based root datum, a notion that simplifies a lot in the quasi-split case (in that a certain intervention of the Weyl group becomes trivial):  see section 12.2 of the course notes http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/249BW16Page/handouts/249B_2016.pdf for the $\ast$-action and how it works out in the quasi-split case in terms of the explicit Galois-twisting that makes the group from the split form.  Coming back to ${\rm{U}}(k'/k, h_n)$, for which we worked out the $k'/k$-twisting to get it from ${\rm{GL}}_n$ above, this gives exactly the recipe you wanted **provided** that we can sort out the role of the identification of ${\rm{GL}}_n$ as its own dual (to rigorously justify the correctness of how we describe the action on the $\mathbf{C}$-group ${}^L{\rm{GL}}_n$). Passing to the dual torus lattice and its dual basis of coroots (due to how ${}^LG^0$ is *defined* as a pinned $\mathbf{C}$-group), we get desired formula on the associated *pinned* "dual ${\rm{GL}}_n$" because the automorphism $f:g \mapsto w({}^tg^{-1})w^{-1}$ satisfies
$${}^t (f({}^tg)) = {}^t(w({}^t({}^tg)^{-1})w^{-1}) = ({}^tw^{-1})({}^tg^{-1})({}^tw) = w({}^tg^{-1})w^{-1} = f(g);$$
the second-to-last equality uses that ${}^tw = (-1)^{n-1}w=w^{-1}$.

Answer (score 4):

Just to put what znt said into answer form: the key reference is Borel's Corvallis paper MR0546608 and the key point is addressed in 1.2 and 2.3. We can formulate the problem as follows. We have a canonical action of the Galois group on the based root datum of the L group but as our example demonstrates, knowing what an automorphism does to the based root datum doesn't actually pin it down precisely. 
Write $\psi_0(G)$ for the root datum. Then we have an element of $\psi_0(G)$ 
and we must choose a lifting of it to an element of $\operatorname{Aut} G.$ In other words, we
must choose a splitting of the exact sequence
$$1\to \operatorname{Inn}\ ^LG \to \operatorname{Aut}\ ^LG \to \operatorname{Aut} \psi_0(^LG) \to 1.$$
For each simple root $\alpha$ choose an element $x_\alpha$ of the corresponding root subgroup. Then for each element $\sigma$ of $\operatorname{Aut} \psi_0(G)$ there is a unique automorphism $\widetilde \sigma$ of $^LG$ which maps one's fixed maximal torus and Borel to themselves and permutes $\{ x_\alpha: \alpha \in \Delta\}.$ A splitting obtained in this way is called admissible. The $L$ group should be defined using an admissible splitting. Changing the choice of $x_\alpha$'s is equivalent to conjugating by the inner automorphism attached to an element of the torus, so it doesn't change the isomorphism class of the group.

Consider the case of a unitary group in four variables. It suffices to consider one symmetric and one skew symmetric option, so let's assume $A$ is 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}&&&1\\&&1&\\&\pm1 &&\\ \pm1 &&&\end{pmatrix}
$$

Let 
$$
x_1(r_1)=\begin{pmatrix}1&r_1&&\\&1&&\\&&1&\\&&&1\end{pmatrix}, 
x_2(r_2)=\begin{pmatrix}1&&&\\&1&r_2&\\&&1&\\&&&1\end{pmatrix}, 
\text{ and } 
x_3(r_3)=\begin{pmatrix}1&&&\\&1&&\\&&1&r_3\\&&&1\end{pmatrix}.
$$ 
Then $g\mapsto A\ ^tg^{-1} A^{-1}$
maps $x_1(r_1)$ to $x_3(-r_1),$ $x_3(r_3)$ to $x_1(-r_3)$ and $x_2(r_2)$ to $x_2(\mp r_2).$ Hence, if we want to choose three elements which are permuted by the action of our automorphism we must take $r_3 = -r_1$ and the sign must be $-.$

One may reasonably ask why sticking to ``admissible'' splittings is the *correct* thing to do. In this regard, I would just note that in either semidirect product $GL_4(\mathbb C) \rtimes \langle$involution$\rangle$ we have the group $(GL_2(\mathbb C) \times GL_2(\mathbb C)) \rtimes \langle$involution$\rangle,$ which is the $L$ group of $\operatorname{Res}GL_2$ (restriction of scalars). For either choice of $A$ above our involution will preserve the parabolic subgroup of $GL_4(\mathbb C)$ whose Levi is $^L\operatorname{Res}GL_2,$ but the action of $^L\operatorname{Res}GL_2$ on the unipotent radical is different in the two cases. So, results in the Langlands-Shahidi method which show that the $L$ function appearing in the constant term is the one attached to the representation we get from the admissible splitting as opposed to the inadmissible splitting make a persuasive case that the admissible one is indeed the *right* one.